# no overloaded function found

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, type-alias

I have class `KeyA` that is from third party and will be the key in use. When I define a "<" operator, it complains:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const KeyA’ and ‘const KeyA’)
```

some simplified code to show the issue:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct KeyA {  // defined in somewhere else
    int a;
};

namespace NS {
struct config {
    using Key = KeyA; // type alias
    using Table = map<Key, int>;
};

bool operator <(const config::Key& lhs, const config::Key& rhs) {
    return lhs.a <rhs.a ;
}
}

int main()
{
    using namespace NS;
    config::Table table;
    table[{1}]= 2;

    return 0;
}
```

What happens here? and how to solve this (no way to touch `KeyA` and most probably have to keep the overloaded function in `NS`)?

Comment: NS is the constraint I have to live with. :-(

Comment: set the operator as freind in you key struct

Comment: why can you not define the `operator<` in the same namespace as `KeyA` ? You dont have to modify `KeyA` for that

Comment: sorry, "KeyA" is some generated code that is untouchable; and also I can only change in "NS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple option is to just define your own comparator and supply that to the `std::map` template arguments instead:

```
struct config
{
    using Key = KeyA; // type alias

    struct KeyLess {
        bool operator ()(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const {
            return lhs.a < rhs.a;
        }
    };

    using Table = map<Key, int, KeyLess>;
};
```

You can leave the other comparison function there if you want.  I removed it, since it looks like you only defined it for the map anyway.

Comment: this is one solution, but for some limits, I cannot add "less" as input. Actually I have some code with this "less", then I tried to get rid of "less", to make this table to be able to work with some template that only takes "K,V".

Comment: Then it sounds like you're breaking encapsulation by passing your table around to things that have no business knowing its underlying implementation.

Comment: some existing templates were written based on the argument such as template <typename K, typename V> void foo(std::map<K, V> m); To make this work, I have to extend like <typename K, typename V, typename L> void foo(std::map<K, V, L> m). Anyway, why cannot the compiler find the overloaded operator?

Comment: It can find it if you put it in a better place: https://godbolt.org/z/aT4n5eKf5 - here you can just define the operator before aliasing the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following complete working [program](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pVwLGG3zor8SDg5O) to solve your problem.

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct KeyA {  // defined in somewhere else
    int a;
    //friend declaration
    friend bool operator <(const KeyA& lhs, const KeyA& rhs);
};
bool operator <(const KeyA& lhs, const KeyA& rhs) {
    return lhs.a <rhs.a ;
}
namespace NS {
struct config {
    using Key = KeyA; // type alias
    using Table = map<Key, int>;
};


}

int main()
{
    using namespace NS;
    config::Table table;
    table[{1}]= 2;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pVwLGG3zor8SDg5O).

Comment: sorry, "KeyA" is some generated code that is untouchable; and also I can only change in "NS"

Comment: @pepero Ok then paddy's solution should be used.